# Matlab Error using mupadmex

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to compile this matlab code,

`

```
lambda = 1/pi;
delta = 3;
alpha = 3.5;
sum = 0;
syms t; 
for k = 1:5
    for l = 0:(k*delta)
        for m = 1:2
           a =  ((lambda*pi)^(l+(alpha/2)+(m*delta)+1))/(factorial(l)*factorial((k*delta) -1)*factorial(m*delta));
           gamma    = @ (t) exp(-t).*t.^((k*delta)-l-(alpha/2));
           f = @ (u) int(gamma,t,u,inf);
           g = @(u) u.^((2*l) - alpha + (2*m*delta+1));
           h = @(u) a.*g(u).*f(u);
           b = integral(@(u) h(u),0,inf);
           sum = sum +b ;
        end
    end
end
sum
```

I get this error,

```
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: The argument is invalid. [Dom::Interval::new]
```

anyone have an idea how to solve this problem ? 
Many thanks,

Comment: On which line? (probably `int`, which doesn't want an anonymous but a symbolic function)

Comment: `int` is symbolic math, `integral` is the corresponding numeric function. What do you want?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply,
Actually, i want to calculate the integral of an incomplete gamma function 
`f = @ (u) int(gamma,t,u,inf); ` 
but i get the error: Error using mupadmex

I don't know where it come from ...